# htpasswd causing 404 when accessing url directly

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, .htpasswd

I have setup a `htpasswd` protection for the WordPress on a staging server to prevent public access.

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protection Lock"
AuthUserFile "path/to/passwd/file"
require valid-user
```

The `htpasswd` works fine, however I noticed a weird issue. I have a contact page, `/contact-us`, and whenever I access that page directly before passing by the home page, all `.css`, `.js` and image files returns a `404` with the following header:

```
WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Protection Lock"
```

Now, if I go by the home page first (`/`), then I click on `Contact Us`, every thing loads fine.

I know it's an htpasswd problem because removing the protection, and accessing the url directly doesn't give me the issue.

I have found a solution to solve it by doing some research online that I have to do add the following to my `.htaccess`:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /401.html
```

And create a `401.html` file at the root with any text inside.
Once I've done it, every thing works fine. Now my question is, how does the solution work? Why is it fixing the problem?

I'm just trying to understand what's happening exactly.